# Sharepoint designer MasterPage after edit error

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I did some changes index.html in sharepoint designer. Although I got the changes back, it happened.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Duplicate ContentPlaceHolder 'PlaceHolderPageTitle' were found. ContentPlaceHolders require unique IDs.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 80:         
>   Line 81:         
>   Line 82:             
>   Line 83:                 
>   Line 84:
>
> Source File: /_catalogs/masterpage/UMA/index.master    Line: 82
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3163.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you give same id's (PlaceHolderPageTitle) to different ContentPlaceholder.

**ContentPlaceHolder should have unique Id's**.

Make sure you are giving unique Id value to each Content placeholder in master page